# Move a file and rename it if the destination folder contains also a file with the same name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sorry for my bad english. I want to move a file from the Desktop to user's input destination.
If destination has also a file with the same name, how can i ask user to rename the file so that he can have them both in destination folder?
I have this right now:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "path"
read path
echo "Do you want to move code files somewhere else?"
read -t 5 y
if [[ $y = 'yes' ]] ; then
echo "Tell me where:"
read mydest
find $path -type f \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cxx" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.cc" \) );do
mv ???
fi
```

Comment: GNU coreutils `man mv`: _--backup[=CONTROL] make a backup of each existing destination file_

Comment: @JamesBrown : I think `--backup` does not help here. The OP wants to interactively request a new file name from the user, if the file already exists.

Comment: @katoutou : Split your problem into two: First write a small script which just moves one file, asking the user for a new name if the destination already exists. Once this is done, use this script in your `find` command. BTW, your `find` would also hit on directories with matching names. If you want to restrict the moving to files only, add the `-type f` predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstrating using `mv` and switches `-i` (interactive) and `--backup`:

```
$ echo foo > foo              # making test files
$ echo bar > bar
$ mv -i --backup foo bar      # mving foo
mv: overwrite 'bar'? y        # -i caused this
$ cat bar                     
foo                           # mv caused this
$ cat bar~                    # --backup caused this
bar
```